# UIView drawRect method does not called when use it instad of UITableViewCell drawInRect in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

After lot more googling and stack-overflowing figure out don't override the `UITableViewCell`Custom class `-drawRect` method and Instead use `UIView` Custom class's `-drawRect` method, Like bellow.

`UITableViewCell`Custom class

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
        [self.contentView addSubview:customView];
        [customView release];
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

`UIView` Custom class

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,0); //start at this point

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 20); //draw to this point

    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

But the problem is **never called** `customView`'s `-drawRect` method.

Comment: can you explain it further so we can help you out.What i understand from your question is that you are unable to call drawRect method.have you tried  [self setNeedsDisplay] or you have made a custom drawRect method?

Comment: Hi Popeye,
What I wan't is Customize UITableViewCell's drawRect method...
I did it and not working as i wish in iOS 7. so i use Custom UIView class's drawRect instead of UITableViewCell's drawRect. the Custom UIView Class drawRect method doesn't called.... that's the problem..

Comment: Hi,i have worked with drawRect its working fine in iOS 7 too.you must debug your code to find why its not calling.